# Comparing Strings in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following code to compare two strings and show a different image depending on the comparison:

```
let sameQuotation = "0"
        if prioridad == sameQuotation {
            print("es 0-")
            let image11 = UIImage(named: "pri0") as UIImage?
        }


        let sameQuotation1 = "1"
        if prioridad == sameQuotation1 {
            print("es 1-")
            let image11 = UIImage(named: "pri1") as UIImage?
        }
```

The "print" action is done perfectly, but the image doesn't change.

I am new to Swift and may be there is something wrong with my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not changing because you're redeclaring `image11` within each conditional. Change `let image11 = ...` to `image11 = ...` to access what I assume is a previously declared version of `image11`, ex:

```
if prioridad == sameQuotation {
    print("es 0-")
    image11 = UIImage(named: "pri0") as UIImage?
}


let sameQuotation1 = "1"
if prioridad == sameQuotation1 {
    print("es 1-")
    image11 = UIImage(named: "pri1") as UIImage?
}
```

Comment: You should accept Lyndsey's answer if it solves your problem. (And up-vote it if you haven't already.)